# before and after image slider not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

sorry in advance for any wrong/poor coding.

I've adapted the following from this original tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzqDU9efnnk&t=61s

When I've adapted it to my code there seems to be an issue and I'm unsure where in the code. Three major problems I can see with it is the left image being bigger than the right, large padding around the whole container, and the slider javascript not working.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Please bear in mind I'm a bit of an idiot when it comes to coding skills so if you could dumb down your answer as much as possible that would be also greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<main class="led-main">
<div class="led-container">
    <div class="led-image-container">
        <img
            class="led-image-before led-slider-image"
            src="/images/products/multiservice-chilled-beams/led-lighting-replacement/101-new-cavendish-before-led-lighting-upgrade.jpg"
            alt="Before LED Lighting Upgrade" title="Image showing the project before the LED lighting upgrade"
            loading="lazy"
        />
        <img
            class="led-image-after led-slider-image"
            src="/images/products/multiservice-chilled-beams/led-lighting-replacement/101-new-cavendish-after-led-lighting-upgrade.jpg"
            alt="After LED Lighting Upgrade" title="Image showing the project after the LED lighting upgrade"
            loading="lazy"
        />
    </div>
    <input type="range" min="0" step="10" max="100" value="50" class="led-slider" aria-label="Percentage of before photo shown"/>
    <div class="slider-line"></div>
    <div class="led-slider-button" aria-hidden="true">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="#000000" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><path d="M136,40V216a8,8,0,0,1-16,0V40a8,8,0,0,1,16,0ZM96,120H35.31l18.35-18.34A8,8,0,0,0,42.34,90.34l-32,32a8,8,0,0,0,0,11.32l32,32a8,8,0,0,0,11.32-11.32L35.31,136H96a8,8,0,0,0,0-16Zm149.66,2.34-32-32a8,8,0,0,0-11.32,11.32L220.69,120H160a8,8,0,0,0,0,16h60.69l-18.35,18.34a8,8,0,0,0,11.32,11.32l32-32A8,8,0,0,0,245.66,122.34Z"></path></svg>
</div><br>
```

CSS:

```
.led-main{
display: grid;
place-items: center;
min-height: 100vh;
}
.led-container{
display: grid;
place-content: center;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 1rem;
--position: 50%
}
.led-image-container{
max-width: 800px;
max-height: 90vh;
aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
.led-slider-image{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
object-position: left;
}

.led-image-before{
position: absolute;
inset: 0;
width: var(--position);
}
.led-slider{
position: absolute;
inset: 0;
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.led-slider:focus-visible ~ .led-slider-button {
outline: 2px solid black;
outline-offset: 3px;
}
.slider-line{
position: absolute;
inset: 0;
width: .2rem;
height: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 10;
left: var(--position);
transform: translateX(-50%)
pointer-events: none;
}

.led-slider-button{
position: absolute;
background-color: #fff;
color: black;
padding: .5rem;
border-radius: 100vw;
display: grid;
place-items: center;
top: 50%;
left: var(--position);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
pointer-events: none;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px hsl(0, 50%, 2%, .5);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const container = document.querySelector('led-container');
document.querySelector('.led-slider').addEventListener
('input' (e) => {
    container.style.setProperty('--position', 
`${e.target.value}%`)
})
</script>
```

Comment: That seems not to be all of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is with your JavaScript code. There is a syntax error in the event listener function. You are missing a comma after the 'input' event and a closing parenthesis and you should use .led-container instead of led-container. Here's the corrected code:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.led-container');
document.querySelector('.led-slider').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    container.style.setProperty('--position', `${e.target.value}%`);
});
```

Comment: Hi Tned, thank you for taking the time to solve / comment. This solves the javascript issues, thanks.

Comment: Hi Tned, sorry I'm fairly new to stack overflow, if I accept your solution to the JavaScript side of the problem does that close the question? As I still need to come back to HTML and CSS side of the problem but its been sidelined at the moment so coming back to it in next two weeks or so.

Comment: no it dosn't close the question

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a display-block on your images

Simply add this to your code and both images should be the same size.

```
img {
  display: block
}
```

If you need some more information about display / display block you can find that here [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) or here [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php)

***The code you provided in action with display block applied to the images:*** *With some placeholder images*

```js
const container = document.querySelector('led-container');
document.querySelector('.led-slider').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  container.style.setProperty('position',
    `${e.target.value}%`)
})
```

```css
img {
  display: block
}

.led-main {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.led-container {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  --position: 50%
}

.led-image-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 90vh;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

.led-slider-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: left;
}

.led-image-before {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: var(--position);
}

.led-slider {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.led-slider:focus-visible~.led-slider-button {
  outline: 2px solid black;
  outline-offset: 3px;
}

.slider-line {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  width: .2rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  left: var(--position);
  transform: translateX(-50%) pointer-events: none;
}

.led-slider-button {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: var(--position);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px hsl(0, 50%, 2%, .5);
}
```

```html
<main class="led-main">
  <div class="led-container">
    <div class="led-image-container">
      <img class="led-image-before led-slider-image" src="https://techcrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/GettyImages-1207206237.jpg?w=1390&crop=1" alt="Before LED Lighting Upgrade" title="Image showing the project before the LED lighting upgrade" loading="lazy"
      />
      <img class="led-image-after led-slider-image" src="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/12/14/well/14google-photo/merlin_178797099_f0a14fdb-8c54-4aad-ba09-4506303b06c3-superJumbo.jpg?quality=75&auto=webp" alt="After LED Lighting Upgrade" title="Image showing the project after the LED lighting upgrade"
        loading="lazy" />
    </div>
    <input type="range" min="0" step="10" max="100" value="50" class="led-slider" aria-label="Percentage of before photo shown" />
    <div class="slider-line"></div>
    <div class="led-slider-button" aria-hidden="true">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="#000000" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><path d="M136,40V216a8,8,0,0,1-16,0V40a8,8,0,0,1,16,0ZM96,120H35.31l18.35-18.34A8,8,0,0,0,42.34,90.34l-32,32a8,8,0,0,0,0,11.32l32,32a8,8,0,0,0,11.32-11.32L35.31,136H96a8,8,0,0,0,0-16Zm149.66,2.34-32-32a8,8,0,0,0-11.32,11.32L220.69,120H160a8,8,0,0,0,0,16h60.69l-18.35,18.34a8,8,0,0,0,11.32,11.32l32-32A8,8,0,0,0,245.66,122.34Z"></path></svg>
    </div><br>
```

Comment: Hi rogierok, I ran the code snippet and there's still a bit of a gap between the left and right image. In terms of the adding the display block to image is there a way I can differentiate this as the .img has been used before in the CSS file

Comment: Yes, you can put the display block inside `.led-slider-image` and it should work the same, I'll look into the gap, I didn't know that wasn't intended to be there haha.

Comment: That looks like the same gap as in the tutorial, Could you explain what you mean with the gap?

Comment: the original from the youtube video doesn't. Think that's where I've gone wrong. I've tried placing the display block to .led-slider-image and it still doesn't appear to do anything

Comment: Since you are already using `img` in your css as you mentioned above could it be that your images are getting changed by that code without you knowing it? Please double check your code. You can also copy my answer's code and then see for yourself it should work, so i can not fix the issue to code I haven't seen yet haha.